# How to use deactivate Webrick's SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, webrick

Last week I tried to debug with SSL activated in webbrick, but I forget how to restore the settings to default(without SSL). Every time I visit a controller, now it shows:

> SSL connection error
>   Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
>   Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

And below is the log from the console, can anyone help?

> [2011-05-10 07:28:43] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
>   [2011-05-10 07:28:43] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12) [universal-darwin10.0]
>   [2011-05-10 07:28:43] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=62854 port=3000
>   [2011-05-10 07:28:58] ERROR bad Request-Line `UQM?x?ʾ???????c??B?????n???BU???*???98?5EDf32?A/??'.

Comment: try following the instructions at this blog post: http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/chris_rohr/configuring_webrick_to_use_ssl.html

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I forced SSL, ran into a bug, removed all of the force SSL code and now I get nothing but error with my app... Webrick must be holding onto the configuration? How do you clear it?

Answer (score 31):

I just ran into this same exact problem today. I added `config.force_ssl = true` to the application.rb file and got the above error. When I removed the line, the error still persisted.

I fixed it by clearing my browser cookies (Chrome in this case) and it works again. It seems the authentication information is saved in the cookie and something i that keeps reverting our requests to HTTPS but does not authenticate correctly so you get that error. Clearing the cookie solves that issue.

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar issue but wasn't able to fix it by clearing cookies on Chrome (nor any other fixes like `rake tmp:clear`), and ended up switching to using thin with SSL enabled as suggested in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11614213

Added this to my Gemfile:

```
group :development do
   gem "thin"
end
```

Then `bundle` and `thin start --ssl`.

Comment: I already used thin and I started to get the ssl error. Then I ran the command you suggested and told the browser to trust the server anyway. Then, I stopped the server and came back with "rails s". It came back to normal. Thanks. By the way... I had this ssl error with chrome (firefox was still working).

Answer (score 3):

I had to use `rake tmp:sessions:clear` (not just `rake:tmp:clear`) as well as clearing cookies in the browser to fix this issue.

Comment: `rake tmp:sessions:clear` does not exist,  might be useful if you provide framework version as well.

Answer (score 1):

Open Chrome Developer Tools, click and hold "page reload" button, you will see some options,pick "Empty Cache and Hard Reload". Did the trick for me.

Comment: For me, this was the solution

Answer (score 0):

Similarly I recieved the same error after adding `config.force_ssl = true` in my config/locales/application.rb file

To remedy an SSL error, simply edit `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_sessions'` in config/initializers/session_store.rb

Changing the `'_app_sessions'` name to anything else will allow you to start your rails server without ssl and without error