# Ruby on Rails WEBrick SSL connection error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, https, webrick

Please help to implement ssl

rails version - 3.2.8

I edtited following files:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rack-ssl'

 # config/application.rb
require 'rack/ssl'
config.middleware.use Rack::SSL
```

I also tried to use

```
# config/application.rb
config.force_ssl = true
```

But it shows

```
SSL connection error
```

when I access mysite:3000/

But it shows normal page if going to https:mysite

Please help,

thanks,

D

Comment: Which development server are you using? WEBrick?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this:

[How to use deactivate Webrick's SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943647/how-to-use-deactivate-webricks-ssl)

The issue is caused by `config.force_ssl = true`. Even if you remove that, which you may not want, you might still have issues with WEBrick giving you this error. You could try clearing cookies, but that still might not work.

A better alternative, if it's an option for you, would be to switch to using the thin server:

```
group :development do
   gem "thin"
end
```

Then:

```
$ bundle
$ thin start --ssl
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/11614213