# Rails get production environment working with SSL on local machin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I am having trouble with my site with precompiled assets looking nothing like my site with assets served on-the-go. So I figured, I should try things out in production.

Here's the problem, when I do, I get:

`!! Invalid request`

in my terminal log and in my browser I see

`Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.`

The graphic designer is not amused at the mess thats up right now, and I'd love to be able to reproduce the problem. Any ideas on how to get past this SSL issue?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943647/how-to-use-deactivate-webricks-ssl ?

Comment: I had the same issue in 4 different browsers.. I appreciate the link tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I've ever been able to get sites implementing SSL working on my development box in production mode has been to set up Apache in front of my rails server (Webrick, or whatever). This is kind of a pain to set up, but it works. You should be able to find a guide on how to set it up using your exact configuration with a quick search. Another option would be to enable SSL via a configuration file, instead of by environment, so you could simply disable it regardless of your current environment. This is assuming everything else is actually correct and working...