# How do I pass params to Rails controller method then return value using JQuery/AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am using a click function to first get the array/position, then post it via an AJAX call to a controller method. I would then like the method to return a boolean value to enable the addClass in the jquery function. The console is consistently throwing a 500 server error.

Here is the .js file:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#backboard").on("click", "div", function(e){
       $("#backboard div").removeClass("selected");
       var val = $(this).data('val');
     $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "https://localhost:3000/chess/:pos",
        data: {pos: {value: val}},
        success: function(d){
          if(d === true){
            $(this).addClass("selected").append("<p>"+val+"<p>");
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

here is the controller.rb file:

```
 class ChessController < ApplicationController
    include ChessHelper

    def new
    @select = false
    @game = Game.new("white", "ARSEFACE!!!")
    @arr = @game.board
    @cpu = @game.cpuName
    @player = @game.playerName



   end

   def select
      pos = params[:pos]
     a = pos[0]
     b = pos[1]

     if(@arr[a][b][0]===@color)
        @select = !@select
     end

     respond_to do |format|
       format.json { render json: @select }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the config/routes.rb:

```
   get '/chess', to: 'chess#new'
   post '/chess/:pos' => 'chess#select'
```

I know I am probably missing something incredibly obvious here, but any help would be appreciated!

PS and the val variable taking the data from the tag does actually have a value. I am trying to pass that value to the controller in order to return true or false, and will eventually be a validation function once I get this basic issue worked out.

Comment: Try adding the param the route is waiting for as `https://localhost:3000/chess/1`, instead `:pos` in your `$.ajax()` function.

Comment: No such luck on that.

Comment: If `@arr[a][b][0]` wouldn't be equal to `@color` then you couldn't render `@select`?

Comment: yes, well, it would not add the class. the color is the player color, and the select should only work if that can be verified by the select function, which will check against the values contained in the board. nonetheless, it shouldn't return a server error?

Comment: I think you'd need to check the console, network tab to see what happens with the ajax request.

Comment: xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null ); appears to b an issue. also now getting an SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR exception in the console log

Comment: Network console says: failed to load response data

Comment: Try hardcoding a value instead @select, what does it print?

Comment: I actually did try hardcoding true there, same issues, not responding.

Comment: Generally in dev mode, when you get a 500 error your server will spit out some useful information, like the type of error that was raised and line number

Comment: throws POST.........(some folder location stuff)....net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
send @ jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:10255
ajax @ jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:9739
(anonymous) @ chess.self-3b4f822….js?body=1:5
dispatch @ jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:5227
elemData.handle @ jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:4879

Comment: @ChadD It'd be better if you included the whole error in the question, formatting it into a code block, but anyway if I had to guess the code shown here is not the cause of the SSL error. Do you have `config.force_ssl = true` set in your application? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943647/how-to-use-deactivate-webricks-ssl

Comment: Ok, the config files are still pretty much default. I clearing browser cookies and it did not help, still receive same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`url: "https://localhost:3000/chess/:pos",` won't be interpolated, unless I'm completely missing something.

With `post '/chess/:pos' => 'chess#select'` you're telling the Rails (its router specifically) to look for a param inside the request path in the position of `:pos`, and when it finds it, set the value of the `params` hash (at `params[:pos]`) to the string at `:pos` in the path.

jQuery doesn't know anything about Rails' router. Neither does Javascript.

To see what I mean, add this to your `routes.rb` file:

`get '/:cookies/and/:cream' => 'application#test'`

in `application_controller.rb`, add the following:

```
def test
  render :text => "I love me some #{params[:cookies]} with my #{params[:cream]}"
end
```

then hit `http://localhost:3000/chocolate-chip/and/milk`

should read "I love me some chocolate-chip with my milk"

Now, assuming your other code is fine,

```
$("#backboard").on("click", "div", function(e){
       $("#backboard div").removeClass("selected");
       var val = $(this).data('val');
     $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost:3000/chess/" + val,
        success: function(d){
          if(d === true){
            $(this).addClass("selected").append("<p>"+val+"<p>");
          }
        }
      });
```

should do it. No need to pass any additional `data` in the ajax function.

Also, don't use HTTPS in development. It'll just cause you headaches.

Comment: thanks, the server log is still throwing the error:                                                           2017-06-02 10:28:27 -0400: HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>